# Docker compose builds image in one directory but not in another

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have docker-compose file which build and image based on Dockerfile.
When I run `docker-compose build service_name` it hangs on `Building service_name`.

However, when I copy all files in another directory, the images is built successfully.

I checked rights, files/directories have 644 or 755. Maybe this will help to locate the issue, part of docker-compose.yml:

```
service_name:
  build: .
  dockerfile: ./build/Dockerfile-service
  links:
    - another_service:another_service
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  command:
    - ./build/setup.sh
  working_dir: /app
```

UPDATE:
I add .dockeignore, however this doesn't work for me, neither in root nor in build directory. I need manually to remove target/temporary files in order to make volume lightweight

Comment: A side note: There's no need to define links in docker-compose.yml because all containers will be linked by default.

Comment: @mayid it might not be needed but it makes sense to specify  explicitally the links, just to know how the various containers interact together.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. It doesn't hang, but takes too long time to process, because  `./:/app` includes every directory and sub-directory. Just add unnecessary stuff to `.dockerignore`. [Here's I found the solution](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2090#issuecomment-142953083)